# Can't get data from lightning:radioGroup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, radio-button

I can't get value selected on lightning:radioGroup. It return `undefined`

```
<lightning:radioGroup aura:id="test"name="testName" options="{! v.options }" required="true" onchange="{! c.handleChangeButtonGroup }"/>
```

Controller

```
handleChangeButtonGroup:function(cmp, event, helper){
    var auraIdField = event.getSource().getLocalId();
    console.log(cmp.find(auraIdField).get("v.value"));
},
```

I don't want using `event.getParam("value");`, just using component get value it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

Component:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
        {'label': 'Option1', 'value': '1'},
        {'label': 'Option2', 'value': '2'}
    ]"/>

    <aura:attribute name="radioGrpValue" type="String" />

    <lightning:radioGroup
        aura:id="radioGrp"
        name="radioButtonGroup"
        label="Choose Your Option"
        options="{! v.options }"
        value="{! v.radioGrpValue }"
        onchange="{! c.handleChange }"
    />
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var radioGrpValue = component.get("v.radioGrpValue");
    console.log('radioGrpValue',radioGrpValue);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add **value** attribute to the radioGroup component and bind it some attribute or sObject field.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="string" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="string[]" default="[
    {'label': 'apples', 'value': 'option1'},
    {'label': 'oranges', 'value': 'option2'}
    ]"/>

    <lightning:radioGroup aura:id="test" name="testName" options="{! v.options }" value="{!v.value}" required="true" onchange="{! c.handleChangeButtonGroup }"/> 
</aura:component>
```

js Controller

```
({
    handleChangeButtonGroup:function(cmp, event, helper){
        var auraIdField = event.getSource().getLocalId();
        console.log(auraIdField);
        console.log(cmp.find(auraIdField).get("v.value"));
    },
})
```