# This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed

Tags: lightning-aura-components

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed
How I Set up my aura attribute

```
<aura:attribute name="LoanStarted__c" type="Condo_Review__c" default ="{'Condo_Review__c': ''}" />
<aura:attribute name="ApplicationStarted__c" type="Condo_Review__c" default ="{'Condo_Review__c': ''}" />
```

I had to set them up like this for others because I couldn’t type in the textboxes for the other fields.

RadioGroup

```
     <th scope="col" class="gap" width="500px" >
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label"><span class="slds-required">*</span>Has the loan been started?</label>
                    <lightning:radioGroup id = "select" options="{!v.options}" value="{!v.LoanStarted__c.Condo_Review__c}" onchange="{!c.handleRadioClick}"  />
      </th>
```

HandleRadioClick

```
({
handleRadioClick : function(){
var opts = document.getElementById('select').value;
}
})
```

Error: 
Error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
>   failed: c:Condominium_Submission_Requester$controller$handleRadioClick
>   [Cannot read property 'value' of null] Failing descriptor:
>   {c:Condominium_Submission_Requester$controller$handleRadioClick}

Comment: This seems like a similar problem [Can't get data from lightning:radioGroup](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/202666/cant-get-data-from-lightningradiogroup/202674) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Do **not** get into the bad habit of using DOM element `id`s in your logic: you can't guarantee that the name you choose is going to be unique in the overall page. For example, what will happen when you have 2 instances of your component in a page? Or some other component in your page also has the same `id` hard coded?

On the other hand, the `aura:id` is generated by the framework and *is guaranteed to be unique*. For your example:

```
<lightning:radioGroup aura:id="select" ...

({
    handleRadioClick : function(component) {
        var group = component.find('select');
        ...
    }
})
```

will reliably find the `lightning:radioGroup`.

(I'm not familiar with that so your current problem may be unrelated to what I am recommending here, thought the error message suggests that the problem is related.)